# Connecting components of a graph using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, graph-theory

I'm trying to label Addresses an Entity ID number based on whether they've been in a transaction together.

The idea is that if an address is in a transaction with another address, it is assumed that all addresses in that transaction, as well as all addresses in future transactions with these addresses, are owned by the same entity.

I'm currently running this on fairly large dataset (~150-180 million obs) in SQL using a loop, but I feel like R's data.table can tackle this much faster and with simpler syntax, I'm just not sure how to do it. Any help is much appreciated!

Here is an example:

```
DT <- data.table(Address=c('A','B','C','A','D','C','E'), Transaction=c(1,1,2,3,3,4,4))

Address  Transaction
      A            1
      B            1
      C            2
      A            3
      D            3
      C            4
      E            4
```

The outcome I'm looking for would look like this:

```
Address  Transaction  Entity
      A            1       1
      B            1       1
      C            2       2
      A            3       1
      D            3       1
      C            4       2
      E            4       2
```

Comment: What happens if A & C are in transaction 5 together? Is that entity 1 or 2?

Comment: If A and C were in transaction 5 together they would be labeled as Entity 1, but in that case the other results of the example above would also change  -- Address E would also be considered Entity 1 (since it was in a Transaction w/ C, and C was in a transaction with A), so everything would be Entity 1.  Should I post a larger example?

Comment: You should post an example that is large enough to adequately represent the problem when people try to test potential solutions.

Comment: So as your data set grows, previous entries are modified retroactively? (I'm assuming you're working with a stream/feed of data.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would proceed by iterating over the addresses. For each address, find its fellows/neighbors and give them all have the same entity ID. The mapping from address to entity can be stored in a separate table and mapped onto the transactions table after the loop is finished.

```
setkey(DT,Address)
AE  <- DT[,.(Address=unique(Address),Entity=NA_integer_)]
eid <- 0L
for (a in AE$Address){

    ts      <- DT[.(a)]$Transaction
    fellows <- DT[Transaction %in% ts, unique(Address)]
    f_ent   <- AE[.(fellows)][!is.na(Entity), if (.N > 0) min(Entity) else 0L]

    a_ent <- if (f_ent == 0L){
        eid = eid + 1L
    } else {
        f_ent
    }

    AE[.(fellows),Entity:=a_ent]
}

DT[AE,Entity:=Entity][order(Transaction)]
#    Address Transaction Entity
# 1:       A           1      1
# 2:       B           1      1
# 3:       C           2      2
# 4:       A           3      1
# 5:       D           3      1
# 6:       C           4      2
# 7:       E           4      2
```

I'm pretty sure this works, but more general example data would help.

---

As you are faced with millions of records, you'll probably want to look into tweaking this to be a little faster. The costliest step is the computation of `fellows`.

You're pretty much tagging [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) of a graph (see [graph-theory](/questions/tagged/graph-theory)). Think of the Addresses as nodes and each Transaction as adding

- new Addresses and
- new links between Addresses.

The R `igraph` package may be of interest; more likely than not, it computes connected components. (I'm not familiar enough with it to know.)

Generally, if your data set is growing, keeping this variable up-to-date will be a real headache, and I think you should see if you can do without it.

Comment: You're absolutely on point with connecting components of a graph.  I'm not familiar with `igraph` either, but I've hesitated because of the number of unique addresses there are in the dataset (+100million).  I'll try running this on a larger set than the example above..

Comment: Ok cool, I've added a link on the term to the answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)

Comment: This is great, totally works.  You're right about the `fellows` line being the costliest computational step.  I might change the title of the question to `Connecting components of a graph using data.table` to better reflect the question and what the code is actually doing.